# Using groovy in apache-nifi

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have  generated  flowfile with attribute date and  then I want to make  some changes on my date:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets 
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback

def flowfile = session.get()
def date=flowfile.getAttribute('date')
 def yourDate= new GregorianCalendar(date)
 def newdate= yourDate.getTimeInMillis()+621355968000000000
if(!flowfile) return
flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, '12321312'+'_'+newdate)
session.transfer(flowfile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

but executescript posecor gives me exception:Cannot invoke getAtribute on null object , what should i do?

Comment: is  there any nifi processor except  executescript i can  use to do same job

Comment: what is the format in the `date` attribute? what means this magic number - `621355968000000000` (19M years)? in your code you have to put `if(!flowfile) return` just after the line with `session.get()`

Comment: There are 621355968000000000 epoch ticks Ist Jan 1900 to Ist Jan 1970. (i need to convert date to Ticks)

Comment: and what is the date format?

Comment: ISO standart .......

Comment: could you provide an example value of `date` attribute and what you want to see as a result after processing.

Comment: date attribute is like :2012/02/02  00:00:00.000'Z' and after executing code in executescript processor i want to get 6214887820800000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have the `date` attribute with value : `2012/02/02 00:00:00.000'Z'`

#### the groovy code to parse the `date` and convert it to milliseconds could be like this:

```
def flowfile = session.get()
if(!flowfile) return
def date=flowfile.getAttribute('date')
//parse the string that contains date to java.util.Date
date = Date.parse('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SS', date)

//get milliseconds
def millis = date.getTime()
//add some magic number ?
millis+=6200000000000000
//set new attribute value
flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, 'date', '12321312'+'_'+millis)
session.transfer(flowfile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

#### all above you can do with `UpdateAttribute` processor_

just define the new property named `date` with the following [nifi expression](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html):

```
12321312_${date:toDate("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SS"):toNumber():plus(6200000000000000)}
```

#### both variants gives the result:

```
12321312_6201328133600000
```

PS: I still don't understand what is the value that you expect `6214887820800000`

Comment: thank  you , after using updateprocessor can i use the  value in this case 6201328133600000 as an argument for invoking service in invokehttp ,i have tried it by ${date} (without it '12321312') and it didn't work

Comment: now it's  work i mised semicolons , thank  you it was very  helpful

Answer (score 0):

I guess  this is  solution:

```
 import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets 
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.GregorianCalendar

def flowfile = session.get()
if(!flowfile) return
def date=flowfile.getAttribute('fromDate')
 SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
  def d=new Date(format.parse(date).getTime());
  def newdate=new GregorianCalendar(d.getYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDay() )
 def TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000;
 def TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND= 10000;
  def TickSolution=(newdate.getTimeInMillis() - TICKS_AT_EPOCH) / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND

flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, 'filename','Info'+'_'+date)
session.transfer(flowfile, REL_SUCCESS)
```